# Python subprocess execute command with \ in command string

Tags: python, command-line

I'm writing a simple program that takes in a command line string and executes it.

An example command line string could be dir "c:\users\xxx\My Documents"

I'm having trouble trying to execute this due to the '\'. I've specified a dir name as an example of a string that has a backslash in it.

Since the command I receive could be anything - say regex's etc, the \ should be maintained. How would I ensure that the user input stays as entered in the python script?

```
import platform
import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    command = sys.argv[0].split()

    if platform.system().lower() == 'windows':
        runShell = True

    out = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=runShell,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    for line in out.stdout.readlines(): 
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: How do you know ` \ ` is the problem? My 1st bet would be this bizzare splitting.

Comment: `backslash` works OK, use `str(smth)` to be sure. Splitting looks strange too.

Comment: How would you split the string?

Comment: The \ is a problem as the way the string splits in the example I used is ['dir','c:\\Program Files'] ... (I have a subroutine I call to concat strings within "" in my command str). When I try to run the command the dir cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer on how to parse shell commands provided as a string to a py module.

Use the shlex module - https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html to split the command str into a list that can be executed by the subprocess.Popen method.